# How to enable auto-slide in bootstrap carousel with 2 images and one video every 10s?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, slider

i'm trying to create a slider which is combination of images and videos.

i tried to implement using bootstrap but, i am failing to do so.

here's the code below

```
<div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--Indicators-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!--Indicators-->
  <!--Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!--First slide-->
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <!--/First slide-->
    <!--Second slide-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <video src="./video/video1.mp4" autoplay poster="./images/boardwalk.jpg"></video>
    </div>
    <!--/Second slide-->
    <!--Third slide-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(70).jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <!--/Third slide-->
  </div>
</div>
```

> I need three slides, with two image slides, and one to be a video slide, that changes every 15s.

Is there any way to add custom slide using jquery

Comment: https://codepen.io/doodlemarks/pen/xDvAw Check this link can be very interesting for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ for a jquery slider. I think it will help you a lot.

I've made an **example** one for you below:

```js
//Initialize your slider in your script file
$("#carousel-slider").slick({
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1500,
    mobileFirst: true
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<div id="carousel-slider">
<div>
    <img style="width:100%; height:100%;" class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div>
    <video style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" autoplay></video>
</div>
<div>
    <img style="width:100%; height:100%;" class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(70).jpg" alt="Third slide">
</div>
</div>

<!-- Calling jQuery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Calling Slick Library -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

You can change 'autoplaySpeed' to whatever interval you'd like it to change.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `data-interval` attribute to your bootstrap carousel to automatically scroll to next slide every `x` seconds. Do note that `data-interval` calculate your value in **`milliseconds`** so if you want to change the carousel slides after every 10 seconds, you need to add `data-interval=10000`.

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example on how to use the `data-interval` attribute to auto slide your carousel:

```css
/* CSS */

html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-item img {width: 100%; height: 200px;}
.carousel-item video {width: 100%; height: 200px;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
      <!--Indicators-->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!--Indicators-->
      <!--Slides-->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!--First slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <!--/First slide-->
        <!--Second slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <video controls>
            <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
        <!--/Second slide-->
        <!--Third slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(70).jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <!--/Third slide-->
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How could i use videos that are **saved in local directory**, while i try to do so, i do not get any video, but working with videos in url.